# It seems ambiguous to me

Tags: ambiguity

Q1. What is "**invisible earnings**"? I can't find out the meaning or example sentence in my dictionary. Is it some 'profits related to mind or spirit'?

Q2. My dictionary says "**invisible green**" is "very dark green". How can it be so? Doesn't 'invisible' mean 'transparent'? So 'Transparent green' is 'light green, isn't it? Would you explain why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/invisible) offers this definition of **invisible**:

> used to refer to money that is added to a country's economy by activities such as the service and financial industries rather than the production of goods in factories

[Invisible green](https://www.quora.com/How-do-green-screens-become-invisible-and-show-the-thing-behind-them) is not invisible. It is a colour that can be used to digitally render an alternative image into the part of a picture or video that is this shade of green. I don't know whether they still do it that way, but weather presenters used to stand in front of a green screen, then the weather map was digitally added to the area that was green.

Comment: Your answer to Q1 couldn't be clearer. But Q2 answer is a little bit hard for me to understand. Anyway, thank you for your time and answer:)

Comment: @mystery put in simple terms, "invisible green" is not a real colour, and it's not invisible. It's a special term used to describe an image processing technique. Have a look at the link for more information.